# Cómo cambiar lenguaje de Resources en api .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, controller, .net-core

deseo saber como puedo cambiar el lenguaje de mi api .net core al iniciar definiendo en el appsettings.json cuál será el lenguaje a usar. 
He visto muchas página que hablan de localización y globalización pero lo que necesito no es tan complejo como eso.

Me explico...
Tengo dos recursos para dos idiomas, ingles(Language) y español(Language.es-Es):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego en mi **appsettings.json** defino si usaré "en" ó "es"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y establezco el cambio en el Startup:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, sólo deseo que dependiendo de la configuración, en el controlador se devuelvan los mensajes en el idioma especifico:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero a todas las peticiones que hago, **siempre obtengo la respuesta en español :( **

**¿Qué puedo hacer para que obtenga adecuadamente el cambio a otro idioma cuando inicio la aplicación ?**

Comment: Para una próxima pregunta no agregues imagenes, solo coloca el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomando tu lenguaje del json, se lo pasas como especificacion a la propiedad `Culture` de `Resource` y con eso debe funcionar.
Debes respetar los nombres de los archivos, por defecto `Resource.resx` corresponde a ingles y los demas resource que crees debes colocarle la cultura al archivo antes de la extension, en este caso colocaste ES pero tambien puede ser ES-es. `Resources.Es.resx`

```
string language = appSettings.Language;
Resource.Culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
```

Otra manera de hacerlo es:

```
 string language = appSettings.Language;
 CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
```

De esta forma te toma de forma automatica para toda la app la configuracion.

Comment: No hay que agregar? :                                   
 CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

Comment: Es otra manera de hacerlo, cualquiera de las dos te puede servir. Si te sirvio la respuesta marcala como aceptada.